# HighCharts long title text overlapping on some elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

I have a chart container Div which loads all the chart and titles similar to fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/a6zsn/188.  I have a another div placed exactly after the title text and before the chart which contains a multiple dropdowns side by side. 
The problem i am facing is, when the title is too long it goes under the dropdowns. I want to have an auto adjustment like if title goes long into next line, The dropdowns and chart should adjust accordingly.

Example i have another div after the

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<div id="someID">Dropdowns</div> // this is where i am failing and text overlaps on to
```

Can anyone have idea to overcome this?

Comment: title of what is too long?

Comment: title of high charts. I tried to add some text or drop down box to your container div in fiddle. But why can't i see any thing that is added to container div in html - in fiddle?

Comment: I am facing problem with only title of highCharts not with tooltips?

Comment: you said title text is overlapping if you have a longer title. where is it overlapping, I tried increasing the length of your title text, but it is not overlapping, instead it is adjusting properly

Comment: Yeah, But there is no dropdown in the given fiddle. Just assume, you have a drop down after the title text(with 200 characters or dynamically increasing) and just before the chart starting. That is where i am facing the issue. Is there any way that i can find the characters in highcharts title in advance and set the dropdown adjusted their position accordingly along with chart.

Comment: why can't you add a drop down in fiddle?

Comment: See this http://jsfiddle.net/a6zsn/188/

Comment: Duplicate question (even from same user ^^):
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29529127/highchart-container-does-hold-inner-div/29533367#29533367

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to position the "#some"-div programmatically as explained in the same question you asked here ;)

[Highchart container does hold inner div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29529127/highchart-container-does-hold-inner-div/29533367#29533367)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the css to this:

```
#some {
display: inline-block;
margin: 20px 40px;
position: relative;
}
```

And the html layout to this:

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0   auto">

</div>
<div id='some'>
  <select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option value="more">More</option>
    <option value="lidl">Lidl</option>
    <option value="coop">COOP</option>
    <option value="ICA">IKA</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Look at the jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Stenvh/c9azwoku/

Comment: NO, I dont want to display Dropdowns on top to title. They should be always after the title and before the chart starts. Your solutions will not work in my case.